Why is my proxy displaying, "You are not connected to the Internet?"
I have a live server on a proxy, and whenever I search something up, it just says, "You are not connected to the Internet" or something like that. I think it may be due to the use of an iFrame and the X-Frame-Options HTTP header, but I'm not sure how to avoid it. Here's the relevant parts of the code:
Server.js:
const express = require('express');
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');
const app = express();
const port = 5500;

app.use(express.static('public'));

const rewriteUrls = (html, baseUrl) => {
  return html.replace(/(href|src)="([^"]*)"/g, (match, attr, url) => {
      const absoluteUrl = new URL(url, baseUrl).toString();
      return `${attr}="/proxy?url=${encodeURIComponent(absoluteUrl)}"`;
  });
};

app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  const query = req.query.q;
  const googleSearchUrl = `https://www.google.com/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(query)}`;
  https.get(googleSearchUrl, (response) => {
      let data = '';
      response.on('data', chunk => {
          data += chunk;
      });
      response.on('end', () => {
          const rewrittenData = rewriteUrls(data, googleSearchUrl);
          res.send(rewrittenData);
      });
  }).on('error', (err) => {
      res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err.message);
  });
});

app.get('/urls', (req, res) => {
 let targetUrl = decodeURIComponent(req.query.url);
 const client = targetUrl.startsWith('https://') ? https : http;
 console.log(`Fetching URL: ${targetUrl}`);

 client.get(targetUrl, (response) => {
   let data = '';
   response.on('data', (chunk) => {
     data += chunk;
   });
   response.on('end', () => {
     res.send(data);
   });
 }).on('error', (err) => {
   console.error('Error fetching URL:', err.message);
   res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err.message);
 });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Index.js:
let tabCount = 1;

function showTab(tabId) {
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content');
    tabs.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove('active'));
    document.getElementById(tabId).classList.add('active');
    const tabElements = document.querySelectorAll('.tab');
    tabElements.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove('active'));
  event.target.classList.add('active');
}

function addNewTab() {
  tabCount++;
  const newTabId = `tab${tabCount}`;
  const newTab = document.createElement('div');
  newTab.className = 'tab';
  newTab.textContent = `Tab ${tabCount}`;
  newTab.setAttribute('onclick', `showTab('${newTabId}')`);
    document.querySelector('.add-tab').before(newTab);
    const newTabContent = document.createElement('div');
    newTabContent.id = newTabId;
    newTabContent.className = 'tab-content';
    newTabContent.innerHTML = `
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google Logo" class="logo">
      <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" id="${newTabId}-search-input" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL">
        <button onclick="browse('${newTabId}')">&#x1F50D;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button onclick="browse('${newTabId}')">Google Search</button>
      </div>
      <div class="search-results">
        <div id="${newTabId}-content-display" class="content-display"></div>
      </div>
    `;
  document.body.appendChild(newTabContent);
}

function browse(tabId) {
  const searchInput = document.getElementById(`${tabId}-search-input`);
  const iframe = document.getElementById(`${tabId}-iframe`);
  const inputValue = searchInput.value.trim();
    if (!inputValue) return;
    const isUrl = /^https?:\/\//i.test(inputValue);
    let fetchUrl;

    if (isUrl) {
      if (inputValue.includes('youtube.com/watch')) {
        const videoId = new URL(inputValue).searchParams.get('v');
        fetchUrl = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${videoId}`;
      } else {
        fetchUrl = `/urls?url=${encodeURIComponent(inputValue)}`;
      }
    } else {
      fetchUrl = `/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(inputValue)}`;
    }

  console.log('Fetching URL:', fetchUrl);
  iframe.style.display = 'block';
  iframe.src = fetchUrl;
}


document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    const activeTab = document.querySelector('.tab-content.active');
    const activeTabId = activeTab.id;
    browse(activeTabId);
  }
});

Index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Thing</title>
 <style>
   body {
     font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     background-color: #f1f3f4;
   }
   .tabs {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     background-color: white;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
     padding: 10px 0;
     position: sticky;
     top: 0;
     z-index: 10;
   }
   .tab {
     padding: 10px 20px;
     margin: 0 5px;
     cursor: pointer;
     font-size: 16px;
     color: #5f6368;
     border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
     transition: border-color 0.3s;
   }
   .tab:hover {
     color: #202124;
   }
   .tab.active {
     color: #1a73e8;
     border-bottom: 3px solid #1a73e8;
   }
   .add-tab {
     font-size: 24px;
     font-weight: bold;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: #5f6368;
     padding: 0 10px;
     transition: color 0.3s;
   }
   .add-tab:hover {
     color: #202124;
   }
   .tab-content {
     display: none;
   }
   .tab-content.active {
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     margin-top: 50px;
   }
   .logo {
     margin: 20px auto;
   }
   .search-box {
     margin: 20px auto;
     width: 60%;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     border: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
     border-radius: 24px;
     background-color: white;
     padding: 5px 15px;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
   }
   .search-box input {
     flex: 1;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     font-size: 16px;
     padding: 10px;
   }
   .search-box button {
     background: none;
     border: none;
     cursor: pointer;
     color: #5f6368;
     font-size: 18px;
   }
   .buttons {
     margin: 20px auto;
   }
   .buttons button {
     margin: 5px;
     padding: 10px 20px;
     font-size: 14px;
     color: white;
     background-color: #1a73e8;
     border: none;
     border-radius: 4px;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: background-color 0.3s;
   }
   .buttons button:hover {
     background-color: #1669c1;
   }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="tabs">
   <div class="tab active" onclick="showTab('tab1')">Tab 1</div>
   <div class="add-tab" onclick="addNewTab()">+</div>
 </div>
 <div id="tab1" class="tab-content active">
   <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google Logo" class="logo">
   <div class="search-box">
       <input id="tab1-search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search Google or type a URL">
       <button onclick="browse('tab1')">&#x1F50D;</button>
   </div>
   <div class="buttons">
       <button onclick="browse('tab1')">Google Search</button>
   </div>
   <div class="search-results">
       <iframe id="tab1-iframe" class="search-iframe" style="width: 100%; height: 80vh;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
   </div>
 </div>
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


Can you add more details? Where does this message come from? What does the server do? How do you configure the proxy in the browser?

Yes; this message comes from when I go on youtube on my proxy and click another video; it just displays this, my guess, again, is iFrames with the X-Frame-Options header. The backend server (server.js) uses express and a bunch of event listeners (/search and /url) to listen for search requests and url requests, and then it uses my computer to request the searches / url and then forwards response to frontend. To host the server, put index.html, server.js, and index.js into vsc and open with live server. Then, using the same port, use node server.js in terminal to run the backend server. Thanks!
